# algorithm for equal groups according to Parameters

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, machine-learning

I have some people's data .each people has grades for few parameters

I want to divide the peoples for N groups that will be as equals as possible in all the parameters.

the parameters are rating. for example - it is most important that parameter 1 will be

equals in the groups,the second parameter is in second priority and the last parameter is The least priority

for example :

there are 100 peoples with data like this:

```
people1 = ["param1"=12,"param2"=70,"param3"=6]

people2 = ["param1"=9,"param2"=79,"param3"=2]
```

and I want to divide the peoples to 3 groups (more or less in a same size)

that will have as most as possible  equals grades

can someone help me? give idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your requirements are a bit vague.  But you may be interested in [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Comment: This question is more like a client searching for a programmer to formulate the requirements from vague notions and not like seeking an advise. Please try to elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

This post makes me think of me being kid and playing soccer games in the yard with other kids.

There were 2 captains selected, and each one chosen turn by turn one player from the pool for the team. This way teams were balanced at the end.

You sure can make an algorithm from this story, and it's super easy (even for kids :) and brings good results on large amount of data.

Only thing you need - to sort the data by "Strength" of players and divide them.